# Repeat.Any() seems to override Repeat.Once()

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I'm using Rhino Mocks 3.6 and I setup a mock were I want a method to return true the first time and then false for every time after that.  I did that by specifying `.Return(true).Repeat.Once()` then `.Return(false).Repeat.Any()`.  But that seems to make it return false all the time.  Instead I had to change the second one to `.Return(false).Repeat.AtLeastOnce()`. I'm wondering why `Any()` behaves this way.  Here's some example code.  The first test will fail while the second will succeed.

```
[TestClass]
public class ExampleTest
{
    private Example example;

    private IFoo foo;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void InitializeTest()
    {
        example = new Example();
        foo = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<IFoo>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
        foo.Expect(f => f.SomeCondition()).Return(true).Repeat.Once();
        foo.Expect(f => f.SomeCondition()).Return(false).Repeat.Any();
        foo.Expect(f => f.SomeMethod()).Repeat.Once();

        example.Bar(foo);

        foo.VerifyAllExpectations();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test2()
    {
        foo.Expect(f => f.SomeCondition()).Return(true).Repeat.Once();
        foo.Expect(f => f.SomeCondition()).Return(false).Repeat.AtLeastOnce();
        foo.Expect(f => f.SomeMethod()).Repeat.Once();

        example.Bar(foo);

        foo.VerifyAllExpectations();
    }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    bool SomeCondition();

    void SomeMethod();
}

public class Example
{
    public void Bar(IFoo foo)
    {
        if (foo.SomeCondition())
        {
            if (!foo.SomeCondition())
            {
                foo.SomeMethod();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the `Any` method is as follows (*THEIR spelling and grammar*):

`Repeat the method any number of times.  This has special affects in that this method would now ignore orderring`

So, in short, `Any` is designed to **ignore** **ordering**

This raises the question of how would you set the first expectation to return one result, and then **any** call after that to return a different result? It seems the best you can do is to use `Times` with the min and max parameters:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test2()
{
    foo.Expect(f => f.SomeCondition()).Return(true).Repeat.Once();
    foo.Expect(f => f.SomeCondition()).Return(false).Repeat.Times(0, int.MaxValue);
    foo.Expect(f => f.SomeMethod()).Repeat.Once();

    example.Bar(foo);
    example.Bar(foo);
    example.Bar(foo);

    foo.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```